# Character replace in String from database (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView and each row I cliked display a UIViewController containing information store in my database like this:

```
[self.myViewController.myViewControllerDescription setText:[self.fiche description]];
```

The information store in the database contains HTML syntaxe ( < BR > ) and I display them in a UITextView (as you know the UITextView will not recognize the < BR > tag),

**I wanna know how can I find this character inside my result and replace it with word wrap, I thik its'/n'**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some string, you can find all instances of `<br>` and replace them with the "newline" character (denoted in C and Objective-C by `\n`) with the NSString method [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6), as such:

```
NSString *stringWithNewlines = [stringWithBRs stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: The problem is that the /n is not recognize in the UITextView, it will just write /n, so what do I have to use?

Comment: Yes I know sorry I just made a mistake when I write. And I know why it didn't work too when I write withString:@"\n", I have to write withString:@" \n" I forget to put a space. Thank you~~

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 - (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```