# What is the right way to replace a given unicode char in an NSString instance?

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, nsstring

I have an NSString instance (let's called it `myString`) containing the following UTF-8 unicode character: `\xc2\x96` ( that is the long dash seen in, e.g., MS Word ).

When printing the NSString to the console using `NSLog` and the `%@` format specifier, the character is replaced by an upside-down question mark indicating that something is wrong - and when using it as text in a table cell, the unicode character simply appears as blank space ( not the empty string - a blank space ).

To solve this, I would like to replace the `\xc2\x96` unicode character with a "normal" dash - at first I thought this should be a 10 sec. task but after some research I have not yet found the "right way" to do this and this is where I would like your help.

*What I have tried:*

When I print `myString` in hex like this `NSLog(@"%x", myString)` I get the hex value: `96` for the unicode character representing the unicode character `\xc2\x96`.

Using this information I have made the following implementation to replace it with its "normal" dash equivalent:

```
for(int index = 0; index < [myString length]; index++)
{
    NSLog(@"Hex:'%x' Char:'%c'", [myString characterAtIndex:index],[myString characterAtIndex:index]);

    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", [myString characterAtIndex:index]] isEqualToString:@"96"])
        myString = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1) withString:@"-"];
}
```

... it works, but my eyes don't like it, and I would like to know if this can be done in much more cleaner and "right" way? E.g. like C#'s `String.Replace(char,char)` [which supports unicode characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) .

*So to wrap up:*

I'm looking for the "right way" to replace unicode chars in a string - I have done some research, but apparently, there is only methods available that replaces occurrences of a given `NSString` with another `NSString`.

*I have read the following:*

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5223737/700926
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217703/700926
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/714009/700926
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/668254/700926
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2039396/700926

... but all of them explains how to replace a given `NSString` with another `NSString` and do not cover how specific unicode characters ( in particular double byte ) can be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your string mutable (i. e. use an NSMutableString instead of an NSString). Also, the call to `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", character] isEqualToString:@"96"]` is as inefficient as possible - why not simply `if (character == 0x96)`? All in all, try

```
NSString *longDash = @"\xc2\x96";
[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:longDash withString:@"-"];
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks! I'm new at objective-c programming, so I'm happy that pros are willing to help ;)